# Is "clear of" an adjective phrase in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjective-phrases

I came across this sentence in an [online article](https://www.si.com/soccer/2017/10/12/jose-mourinho-reportedly-set-bumper-new-5-year-manchester-united-contract)

> United are currently second in the table, seven points **clears of** their north west rivals after seven games, level on points with neighbours Manchester City and trailing only on goal difference.

Isn't **clear of** an adjective phrase in this sentence?

Comment: @LawrenceC Why did you edit the quote? It is *clears* in the article. Just calling it a typo. would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**clear of** is not an adjectival phrase on its own. In this context, **clear** is an adjective meaning **separate from**: see [Oxford Dictionary meaning 4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clear).

This sentence actually contains four adjectival phrases:

> **second** in the table 
>   seven points **clear** of their north west rivals after seven games 
>   **level** on points with neighbours Manchester City 
>   **trailing** only on goal difference.